# Eclipse Error with Generics versus Functionally Similar Method

Tags: java, generics

I have a `Foo<T extends Foo<T>>` abstract class. I want to store instances of its implementation based on its parent class, so I store them in a map `private static final Map<Class<? extends Foo<?>>, Foo<?>> FOOS = new HashMap<>();` To add to this map a method is called using the parent class then initializing it through reflection.

```
public static Foo<?> addFoo(Class<? extends Foo<?>> foo) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return Optional.ofNullable(Foo.FOOS.get(foo)).orElse(Optional.ofNullable(Foo.FOOS.put(foo, foo.newInstance())).orElse(Foo.FOOS.get(foo)));
}
```

However this produces an error in Eclipse: `The method orElse(Foo<capture#25-of ?>) in the type Optional<Foo<capture#25-of ?>> is not applicable for the arguments (Foo<capture#29-of ?>)`

And yet this functionally similar method produces no error.

```
public static Foo<?> addFoo(Class<? extends Foo<?>> foo) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Optional<Foo<?>> possibleFoo = Optional.ofNullable(Foo.FOOS.get(foo));
    if(possibleFoo.isPresent()) {
        return possibleFoo.get();
    }
    //The set to possibeFoo with an Optional is not needed, but this is for demonstration purposes
    possibleFoo = Optional.ofNullable(Foo.FOOS.put(foo, foo.newInstance()));
    return Foo.FOOS.get(foo);
}
```

Why does the first give off an error yet the second doesn't even though it's functionally similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simpler example that produces the same problem.

```
static void example(List<?> list1, List<?> list2) {
    Optional.of(list1).orElse(list2);                // compile error
}
```

This looks like it should work. `Optional.of(list1)` is an `Optional<List<?>>` so the method `orElse` should apply?

The problem here is the way captures work. Suppose `list1` were a `List<String>`. Then we would want `Optional.of(list1)` to be an `Optional<List<String>>`. On the other hand, if `list1` were a `List<Integer>` we would want `Optional.of(list1)` to be an `Optional<List<Integer>>`. So the compiler doesn't treat the type of `Optional.of(list1)` as being an `Optional<List<?>>`, but rather as an `Optional<List<X>>` for some unknown type `X`.

Because the type `X` is not known and the type of the items of `list2` is not known either, they might not match.

You can get around this by telling the compiler you really do want the type to be `Optional<List<?>>`:

```
Optional.<List<?>>of(list1).orElse(list2);   // compiles fine.
```

Your example is essentially the same. You can get it to compile like this.

```
return Optional.<Foo<?>>ofNullable(FOOS.get(foo))
    .orElse(Optional.<Foo<?>>ofNullable(FOOS.put(foo, foo.newInstance()))
    .orElse(FOOS.get(foo)));
```

In general, if you have problems getting a long line of code involving wildcards and generic types to compile, I think it's a good idea to break it up into several lines, declaring the types of some of the expressions on the way (just like you did in the second example).

Comment: That makes more sense now that I see it broken down. I guess I just assumed the compiler would assume the two captures would be identical since it's only coming from one source `Class<? extends Foo<?>> foo`. Thanks

Comment: Wildcards are treated separately even if they come from the type of the same instance. For example `Optional.of(list1).orElse(list1);` doesn't compile either, even though it's the same list twice.

Comment: @danthonywalker - see also http://bayou.io/draft/Wildcard_Case_Studies.html#Unexpected_Capture